# My decorate singleton does not work

Tags: python, singleton

I have a singleton.py, its code is bellow :

```
from functools import wraps

def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}

    @wraps(cls)
    def getinstance(*args, **kw):
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kw)
        return instances[cls]
    return getinstance

@singleton
class OTConn():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = None
```

And I have a test01.py:

```
from app04 import singleton

ot_conn = singleton.OTConn()

ot_conn.conn = "a"
```

And `test02.py`:

```
import singleton

ot_conn = singleton.OTConn()

print (ot_conn.conn)  # there print: None
```

I run the `test01.py`and the `test02.py` in one process, but the `ot_conn.conn` prints `None`.

---

**EDIT**

I tried change the code to :

```
@singleton
    class OTConn():
        conn = None
        def __init__(self):
            pass
```

Still not work. Some friend can help me with the decorate method for singleton?

---

**EDIT-2**

See this [singleton method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python)

the decorator method is as same as mine.

Comment: Your singleton works only when called from the same process. If you are running two processes (one in PyCharm, one in console), you'll need to use some inter-process-communication (IPC) mechanism.

Comment: @randomir In one process still goes the None result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have not understood how to use the `singleton` decorator. You are working under the mistaken assumption that the class you decorate with `singleton` becomes an *attribute* of `singleton`. It does not.

Here is an example of how it works. Note that I have slightly modified the definition of `singleton` to remove some cruft. It only works in Python 3. If you need to use this decorator in Python 3, some of the cruft will have to be put back.

```
from functools import wraps

def singleton(cls):
    instance = None
    @wraps(cls)
    def getinstance(*args, **kwds):
        nonlocal instance
        if instance is None:
            instance = cls(*args, **kwds)
        return instance
    return getinstance

# Check that it works ... first use the decorator on a class definition
@singleton
class Foo:
    pass

# Now instantiate the class twice ...
a = Foo()
b = Foo()

# ... and verify that we have only one instance.
assert a is b
```

Python's `is` operator verifies object identity. the `assert a is b` confirms that `a` and `b` are the same single instance.

Here is how verify that it works in a way which resembles a bit more what you tried to do in your test code:

```
# Showing how it works with your example
@singleton
class OTConn:
    # Your class variable `conn` and constructor were completely
    # irrelevant, so I leave them out
    pass

ot_conn_a = OTConn()
ot_conn_a.conn = 'a'

ot_conn_b = OTConn()
assert ot_conn_b.conn == 'a'
```

The most important difference between your code and mine, is that `singleton.OTConn` does not appear anywhere in mine. It cannot possbily work! (Unless there is some code which you haven't shown us, which makes it work.)

## Step-by-step instrctions how to observe `singleton` functioning correctly

The behaviour you report, and your continued refusal to describe *exactly how* it is that you think you are executing this code in a single process, gives the very strong impression that you are executing this in separate processes. As has been pointed out to you by many people, your singleton class **cannot possibly work** in that case.

Here I give you a step-by-step recipe how to observe `singleton` working correctly in multiple *modules* but a single *process*.

Step 1: create a directory (folder) in which you will create the following python source files.

Step 2: **In the directory you created in step 1** create a file called `singleton.py` containing the following code:

```
def singleton(cls):
    instance = None
    @wraps(cls)
    def getinstance(*args, **kwds):
        nonlocal instance
        if instance is None:
            instance = cls(*args, **kwds)
        return instance
    return getinstance
```

Step 3: **In the same directory** create a file called `theclass.py` containing the code

```
from singleton import singleton

@singleton
class TheClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = None
```

Step 4: Again, in the same directory create a file called `client1.py` containing

```
from theclass import TheClass

instance = TheClass()
print("In client1.py instance.conn =", instance.conn)
instance.conn = 'XXXX'
print("In client1.py instance.conn =", instance.conn)
```

Step 5: ... and also a file called `client2.py` containing

```
from theclass import TheClass

instance = TheClass()
print("In client2.py instance.conn =", instance.conn)
```

Step 6: The last file you need should be called `main.py` and contain

```
from client1 import instance as i1
from client2 import instance as i2

print("In main.py i1.conn =", i1.conn)
print("In main.py i2.conn =", i2.conn)

i2.conn = 'YYY'

print("In main.py i1.conn =", i1.conn)
print("In main.py i2.conn =", i2.conn)
```

Step 7: Execute `main.py`

Step 8: observe the output

```
In client1.py instance.conn = None
In client1.py instance.conn = XXXX
In client2.py instance.conn = XXXX
In main.py i1.conn = XXXX
In main.py i2.conn = XXXX
In main.py i1.conn = YYY
In main.py i2.conn = YYY
```

As you can see from the output

- `TheClass` is instantiated in two separate modules.
- the `conn` attribute of the instances starts of as `None`
- Setting this attribute's value to `'XXXX'` sets it for **both** instances.
- Setting this attribute's value to `'YYY'`, this time using the *other* instance to do so, once again changes **both** instances.

The unavoidable conclusion is that `singleton` works as advertised. But this does *crucially* rely on both instances being **in the same process**.

Comment: There are all, I maybe use the wrong code to do the decorator method for singleton.  and if in one process, it still not work as singleton.

Comment: there is no AttributeError on my process.

Comment: @244boy If I paste your 3 code samples into the same file, remove the two imports, and apply the change that appears in your edit, and the execute the whole file, I get an `AttributeError` on the first line that says `ot_conn = singleton.OTConn()`. This is what I expect to happen, becasue **nowhere in the code that you have shown, does `singleton` acquire a `OTConn` attribute**

Comment: See my edit-2, my friend. you will see my method should be correct.

Comment: Nowhere in the post that you link in your second edit, is there a suggestion that the class you are decorating appears as an **attribute of `singleton`**! I repeat: I have verified my theoretical analysis with experiment: the code you have posted gives an `AttributeError` as soon as you say `singleton.OTConn`. Even after your edit.

Comment: @244boy I have edited my answer to show you how to use `singleton`. I have also cleaned up its implementation a little bit.

Comment: I saw your edited answer, and my situation is, many .py files in my actual project, will import the singleton.py, and I set the singleton shared variate to (such as) "a" , if I take out the shared variate in other py file, it is None, I want the set "a".

Comment: @244boy I have edited the answer to give detailed, step-by-step instructions indicating how to observe `singleton` behaving as it is supposed to.

Comment: Thank you, I get it. my mistake is combine the singleton class and the decorate method to a single py file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156414/discussion-between-jacg-and-244boy).